# foreign key constraint giving issue while inserting records

Tags: mysql

I m trying to import data from one table to another table across the schema.but foreign key constraint is giving issue.
Suppose i m having schema one and schema two.
schema one has tables -->

1. user
2. behavior
3. userbehavior(id from user and behavior table are foreign keys in
   userbehavior table)

same way i have tables structure in schema two.
schema 2 has tables-->

1. user1
2. behavior1
3. userbehavior1(id from user and behavior table are foreign keys in userbehavior table)

I have successfully imported records from user to user1 and behavior to behavior1 but when I m trying to import data from userbehavior to userbehavior1 i m getting following error::
cannot add or update a child row.foreign key constraint fails.
wat could be an issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have inconsistent data, which the database refuses to import, and for a good reason.

I'd create `TEMPORARY` tables (i.e. tables that are automatically deleted after the session ends, import the data there, use a few queries that show me the rows from *userbehaviour* that violate the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, clear these up manually and then use `SELECT INTO` to copy the data to the real tables.

Answer (score -2):

cause : There is at least one row in  table *userbehaviour* which have no parent in other table

todo: first remove all foreign key constraints from both schema and Insert and then set constraint back

---

In case of exporting

open exported sql file and write

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`  on the top of the file

and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS==1;`  on the bottom of file

or

export through  **phpMyAdmin** then check  **Disable foreign key checks**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That is a recipe for inconsistent data. If the query analyzer uses the foreign key constraint for an optimization, it will rightfully assume that it holds for all rows, so the result set may be missing rows.

Comment: When performing a SELECT query on this table, the SQL parser will see the foreign key constraint and assume that all values in the relationship table (*userbehaviour*) also exist in the entity tables (*user* and *behaviour*). Thus, JOIN and INNER JOIN are equivalent on this data set; depending on the remainder of the query and analysis data from earlier queries, the optimizer elects what it thinks is most efficient here.

Comment: To elaborate: by claiming that there is a foreign key constraint and then disabling the check, you are effectively lying to the query optimizer about the consistency of the data. If you give false inputs to the query optimizer, there is no guarantee that the result it gives will be correct.